# RestSharp Error :Giving null from the result.Data

Tags: c#, ssis, restsharp

I'm trying to fetch the data from rest api but getting null from the result.data

```
        request4.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request4.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + mytoken);
        request4.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"active\": true }", ParameterType.RequestBody);


        var result = client4.Execute<List<RootObject>>(request4);//getting nullexcception here

        //Console.WriteLine(result);
        //Console.ReadKey();

        foreach (var i in result.Data)

        {
            foreach (var j in i.sales_offices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j.state);
            }
```

}

```
        }


    public class SalesOffice
    {
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }


public class RootObject
      {
          public bool success { get; set; }
          public string message { get; set; }
          public List<SalesOffice> sales_offices { get; set; }

      }
```

and from json I'm getting this result

{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Gtm Cities loaded successfully!",
    "sales_offices": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "_id": "XXXXX5cb57542ed50d82730d7661d",
            "name": "UAXXS",
            "state": "AXXX.P"
        }

Please help me as it is showing no issue in the code

Comment: Try Execute<RootObject>(request4) instead of Execute<List<RootObject>>(request4) and see if that make any difference.

Comment: Hi Nair, Thanks you for your reply.  I tried adding this Execute<RootObject>(request4) i but it is showing foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Program.RootObject' because 'Program.RootObject' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' this error..

Comment: Your response is not a collection but an instance of RootObject; you can only iterate over sales_offices which is part of your RootObject instance.

Comment: Hi Nair, Thanks a lot for your reply. Could you please add changes in my code.. thank you again

Comment: Remove the first `foreach`. You get one object back. not a list of objects.